# Play framework 2.0 Form.bindFromRequest().get() returns empty model

Tags: post, http-post, playframework-2.0

I need to receive same POST data from a socket communication.

This is the code that send the POST and receive the response, and seems to work correctly:

```
String data = "t=" + URLEncoder.encode("Title", "UTF-8") +
    "&u=" + URLEncoder.encode("http://www.myurl.com", "UTF-8");

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9000/adserver");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String output = "Data received\r\n", line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    output += line;
}
wr.close();
rd.close();

return ok(output);
```

This is the code that receive the POST:

```
Form<AdRequest> form = form(AdRequest.class).bindFromRequest();

if(form.hasErrors()) {
    return badRequest("error");
} else {
    AdRequest adr = form.get();
    return ok(adr.t + " - " + adr.u);
}
```

The AdRequest model is defined in this way:

```
public class AdRequest {
    public String t;
    public String u;
}
```

The form object receive the data because I can see them in debug, but the adr object returned by the get() method contains only null values:

```
adr = {
    t: null,
    u: null
}
```

Instead, if I use this code to read the data it works correctly:

```
Map<String, String[]> asFormUrlEncoded = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
return ok(asFormUrlEncoded.get("t")[0] + " - " + asFormUrlEncoded.get("u")[0]);
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Is it a Play Framework bug?

Thanks.

Comment: And where do you name your POST variables? If you want to get them, you have to bind them to your model.

Comment: I was supposing that the binding is done automatically by matching the names of properties. So I'll try now.

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm seeking the documentation (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms), but even the simple code that use the HashMap doesn't work. I get back always null values.
How should I bind them? Could you post an example?

Comment: Can you provide the data of your variable `form` after you've called `form(AdRequest.class).bindFromRequest()`?

Comment: form.toString() print:
`Form(of=class classes.AdRequest, data={}, value=None, errors={})`

Comment: I found a similar post here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/JYlkz_Nh31g
I played a little with the autobuilding option of Eclipse and I was able to bind data with an HashMap, but from the socket post not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is very old, but I'll describe our issue, just in case anyone is in the same situation.

**Short answer**

Try adding setters `AdRequest`.

**Long answer**

I've found that now the form model classes need setters or Play won't fill them. I don't know why. For some colleages, the code works like before, and for me, Play wants setters. No idea.

Debugging `Form.bindFromRequest`, it eventually reaches this line:

```
package org.springframework.beans;

class BeanWrapperImpl {
    ...
    private void setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.PropertyTokenHolder tokens, PropertyValue pv) throws BeansException {
        ...
        throw new NotWritablePropertyException(this.getRootClass(), this.nestedPath + propertyName, matches.buildErrorMessage(), matches.getPossibleMatches());
```

And `matches.buildErrorMessage()` builds a message like this:

```
Bean property email is not writable or has an invalid setter method
```

After adding the setters (e.g. `setEmail`) it works.

**Update:**

We've found that the form binding depends on the **spring framework** version. We were using **4.0.3-RELEASE** and then we updated to **4.0.5-RELEASE**, and that's when the Play forms started to fail.

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me, it seems, was that Eclipse was interfering with the code generation and generally messing up the generated bytecode.

Turning off "Build Automatically" in Eclipse fixed the problem.

This Link helped: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/JYlkz_Nh31g