# Just trying Play framework, the value from the submitted form is null

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework-2.0, h2

I just tried Play framework and I run sample application using template [play-java-intro](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/templates/play-java-intro).

The index page of the application consists of a "Name" textbox and a submit button. If I click the submit button, it will store the "Name" value of the textbox into "Person" table (the database is using H2). However the "Name" value was failed to be sent to the controller. It returned as null value in controller.

[image]

**The Model:** Person.java

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String name;
}
```

**The View:** index.scala.html

```
@()

@main("Welcome to Play") {
    <script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/index.js")'></script>

    <ul id="persons"></ul>

    <form method="POST" action="@routes.Application.addPerson()">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <button>Add Person</button>
    </form>
}
```

**The Controller:** Application.java

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render());
    }

    public static Result addPerson() {
        //The person.name is null here
        Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        person.save();
        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }

    ...
}
```

In controller, the function addPerson is called when "Add Person" button is clicked. The `person` object is returned from `Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();`. The problem is the `name` property from the returned `person` object is null.

Anyone know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Are you passing the `Person` back to the view?

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean, the code are still originally intact, I didn't change any part of them. I have checked with debugger in eclipse, the `Person.name` is null.

Comment: I've only worked with Scala play in the past so I'm going on memory here. Have you tried making the input's name `Person.name`? Also, what version of play are you using? 2.x.x?

Comment: What did you mean by making input's name? I'm using the latest version of the activator (1.2.10). So I guess the Play must be v2.

Comment: I just found out the cause, it's the Eclipse's automatic build messing with the code generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459475/play-framework-2-0-form-bindfromrequest-get-returns-empty-model).

It turned out that Eclipse's automatic build interferes with the bytecode generation.

So this is what I did to clean up the mess:

- In Eclipse, uncheck: Project -> Build Automatically
- In activator console on your project folder, enter command: clean
- Enter command: compile
- Enter command: run

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and still facing this issue! Any possible fix?